# How to add another controller file in CI (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

the title seems stupid. but i met the problem,
now i can just type http://ci.tao2tw.com, then routes to my index.php/entry function
but when i type http://ci.tao2tw.com/order , i wanna routes to another controller 
order.php , however it doesn't work !
is anything wrong in my setting??

now , i can not run test function under order controller by  http://ci.tao2tw.com/order/test . instead, i should type
htpp://ci.tao2tw.com/**index.php**/order/test
i can not figure out??

thank you all in advance~
[image]
[image]
[image]

in routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "index/entry";
$route['order'] = "order"; 
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://ci.tao2tw.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

in controller/index.php (it works fine )

```
class Index extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() // to remember use public
    {
        parent::__construct(); 
        $this->load->helper('url');
        //anchor(); 
    }
    public function entry() //just show index
    {
        $this->load->view('index_view',$data);      

    }

}
```

in controller/order.php ( no work  )

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Order extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() // to remember use public
    {
        parent::__construct(); 
        $this->load->helper('url');

    }
    public function fill($action) // 顯示填寫表單
    {
        echo "test";
    }
   //http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html
    public function order($action)
    {
        echo $action;
    }
}

?>
```

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|flash|images|img|includes|js|language|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
~
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every controller must be called in CI after your *index.php* file.

So if you don't use a .htaccess file, your link to the order controller is like :

```
http://ci.tao2tw.com/index.php/order/
```

The .htaccess allows to skip the index.php file

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

You can so call your controller with :

```
http://ci.tao2tw.com/order
```

Then, if you want to call a method in your order controller your url is :

- without the .htaccess

  http://ci.tao2tw.com/index.php/order/fill
- with the .htaccess

  http://ci.tao2tw.com/order/fill

Comment: it doesn't work for me ,  i put my .htaccess file under root folder of ci . however it doesn't work . but now i can access the order by type http://ci.tao2tw.com/index.php/order/  very stranger

Comment: No you don't have to restart apache. Here my .htaccess file [on pastebin] (http://pastebin.com/a8bxHS5j).

You have to put the file on the / folder on the top of your website.

Comment: hello, thanks for your hot bloody support.it doen't work i update my post.

Comment: Hm, maybe you should remove the line $route['order'] = "order";

Comment: Also, the .htaccess don't seems to be read. Try to write an error in the .htaccess (such as rewriteruuuule) and tell me if you have an internal server error.

Answer (score 2):

sorry, everyboy. i found the solution
so stupid i am.
i use apache 2 and hava a virtual host with file at path : "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ci.tao2tw.com"

i have to change `AllowOverride None` `to AllowOverride All`

Answer (score 0):

yeah, you need to route it like this:

```
$route['order'] = "order/order";
```

the reason is that until you route the url to a model's method, it cannot know what function you want to perform

now, it will call the order() method of your Order module

Comment: not work , i should append index.php/order/ then i can access it. very wired><

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with the .htaccess file. 
Is your application located in a subfolder?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /path/to/app  [add this if your application is under a sub folder]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```